# Rails ignoring expire_page in sweeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

So I have a sweeper set up to listen to a model, Connection. This model is a relational model between the models/controllers Tag and Post. Super standard. When a new Connection is created or destroyed, I want the sweeper to clear the page cache on the corresponding Tag#show (i.e. '/tags/1' for tag id 1, which shows all the associated Posts).

Seems simple, but my expire_page call in the sweeper doesn't do anything, and in the logs, it seemingly just gets skipped over entirely. But with my puts, i know the sweeper is getting called and my expire_cache function that calls expire_page is getting called. And I've tried all kinds of ways of specifying what page to expire as far as referring to the controller (e.g. :controller => :tags, :controller => "tags") and even tried putting in relative urls, but nothing makes a difference.

Within my Tags controller, I have another function that clears the Tag#index page, and that actually works fine. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

So I have this as my sweeper:

```
class CacheSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper

  observe Connection

  def after_create(record)  expire_cache(record) ; end 
  def after_destroy(record) expire_cache(record) ; end 

  def expire_cache(record)
      puts "begin page expire"
      expire_page(:controller => '/tags', :action => 'show', :id => record.tag.id)
      puts "end page expire"
  end
end
```

and here's my Tags controller, condensed:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :destroy]
  caches_page :index, :show
  cache_sweeper :cache_sweeper

  def create
    @tag = Tag.create(params[:tag])
    if @tag.save
      flash[:success] = "Tag added"
      redirect_to :action => "tags", :controller => :admin_pages
      expire_page(:controller => :tags, :action => :index)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @tags.posts.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  end
end
```